# Combining AOP pointcuts in aop.xml without spring

Tags: java, spring, aop

Below is the aspect I am trying to create.  I would like to combine two pointcut expressions into one.  I have seen that this can be done using annotated pointcuts but the same syntax in the xml fails.  can anyone help me?

```
<aspects>
  <concrete-aspect name="com.logger.aspect.InjectionLoggerImpl" 
                   extends="com.logger.aspect.InjectionLogger">
    <pointcut name="loggingInterceptor" 
              expression="execution(* com.*..*.next(..)) || execution(* com.*..*.read(..))"/>
    <pointcut name="methExecInterceptor="some expression"/>
  </concrete-aspect>
</aspects>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Was about to post almost the exact same question. Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: its been a while since I messed with this but I believe I just had a cached value in my IDE.  once I shutdown and restarted the IDE it worked fine with no changes.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with Spring 2.0.x in xml:

> XML style is more limited in what in can express than the @AspectJ style: only the "singleton" aspect instantiation model is supported, and it is not possible to combine named pointcuts declared in XML

[6.4.2. @AspectJ or XML for Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html)

It is however possible in Spring 3.0.x:

> When combining pointcut sub-expressions, '&&' is awkward within an XML document, and so the keywords 'and', 'or' and 'not' can be used in place of '&&', '||' and '!' respectively. For example, the previous pointcut may be better written as:

```
<aop:config>
   <aop:aspect id="myAspect" ref="aBean">

    <aop:pointcut id="businessService" 
      expression="execution(* com.xyz.myapp.service.*.*(..)) and this(service)"/>
    <aop:before pointcut-ref="businessService" method="monitor"/>
   ...

    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

[Spring 3 aop](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-combining)